# handle labels for a multi-headed CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reshape

I'm trying to build a "multi-headed CNN model" so each head is a branch taking in individual multi variant time series Data.

What is not clear to me how to handle the "fit" method or in other words how to properly prepare the y_train. There are 2 classes 0 and 1 for the label

The current architecture is as shown here.
[image: neural net architecture]

the goal is to predict one time_step ahead

input shapes are:

```
A Training Data (1, 903155, 5)
B Training Data (1, 903116, 5)
C Training Data (1, 902996, 5)
```

label shapes:

```
y_train (903155, 1)
```

when doing:
`history = model.fit(x = [A,B,C], y = y_in)`

than i get:
`Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 903155 target samples.`

reshaping y_in to (1, 903155) results in:

```
 expected dense_5 (see image) to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (903155,)
```

strange is that **model.predict([A,B,C])** yield results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some digging I found the answer as  OverLordGoldDragon mentioned the input and output shape was not correct.

A 1d Conv expect the input data always as:
**(Samples, timesteps_per_sample, features_per_sample)**

so in my case (1, 903155, 5) --> (903155, 1, 5)

Comment: What we do if an answer can be better framed is ask the author to edit it, not copy its part and deprive it of credit - especially if author provided further assistance through comments. If you solved the problem largely without my input, it's a different story, but not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem's rooted in mishandling the *batch dimension*; the first dimension of all your layers, and of your data, is the batch dimension. Error explanations below.

---

**Solution**:

`y_train (903155, 1)` is correct, but `A, B,` and `C` probably aren't: they specify ONE sample with dimensions `(903155, 5), (903116, 5),` and `(902996, 5)`, respectively. I doubt this is desired - more likely, the `90...` are *batch dimensions* and should be reshaped as: `(903155, 1, 5)`, etc.

---

**Error explanations**:

- Error 1 is saying that you fed 1 sample (training example) as an input, but 903155 labels
- Error 2 is saying that `dense_5` output is shaped `(None, 1)`, but is expected to be compared against `(None, 903155)` when computing loss

> Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 903155 target samples.  # Error 1
>
> expected dense_5 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (903155,)  # Error 2

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer!
But actually it is intended the input in this case is one sample each so A,B,C are each in the shape (1 sample, X Time steps , and 5 Features )

Since the ```model.predict``` method returns a result the issue must lay in the y_in but i cant figure what it is

Comment: @Sentinan In that case, I don't know what `y_train` even is; for one-step prediction, you have only _one label_ per batch, shaped `(batch_size, 1, features)` - for you, `(1, 1, 5)`. Double-check your problem definition - let me know if still unsure

Comment: ok so when i change the last  fully connected layer to output (None, 903155) than indeed i don't get an error and the model start the training. 

This means right now the model will output 903155 predictions based on one sample is that correct? 


Desired is:
```take a batch of x time steps and make a prediction for t+1```

Comment: @Sentinan That's very far from it; again, your output shape must be `(batch_size, 1, features)` - you are predicting _one_ timestep given `x` timesteps. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276337/proper-way-to-feed-time-series-data-to-stateful-lstm/58277760#58277760) for reference

Comment: @Sentinan Nope, one output will do; in general, for a model with X `Input`s and `Y` distinct outputs, you feed X and Y input data and labels, respectively - in your case, 3 and 1.

Comment: I can accept your answer you brought me back on the right track. My input series is now something like:```(903146, 10, 5) -- (n_sequences, timesteps_per_sequence, n_features)```

the input is shape (903146, 1). This should yield the expected behavior, which is make a prediction for every sequence of 10 time steps!?

Comment: @Sentinan Do you mean the output shape is `(903146, 1)`? And input looks fine right now; the way it should work is, `fit` defaults `batch_size=32` if you don't specify, and will fit slices shaped `(32, 10, 5)` at a time - for a total of `903146//32 = 28200` iterations. That's fairly large, consider setting `batch_size` to something larger, e.g. `128, 256`. As for prediction, it'll predict on as many samples as you feed (unless you specify `batch_shape` for `Input`, then you must feed `batch_size` number of samples)

Comment: yes correct:  output shape is (903146, 1), and great suggestion for batch size testing it. The model looks now as follows: https://i.imgur.com/IYLVtY8.png

the model is now "training" but doesn't do any progress 
it starts with a loss of 0.48740 and stays there no matter how many epochs. Do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: @Sentinan That's a separate question, with scope substantially beyond this one. If you open it as a new question, you can reply here to notify me - I should be able to assist. But briefly: I'd mainly question how you acquired the new input shapes, `(60, 4)`, etc - if via a simple reshape, that could be the root of the problem.