# Tensorflow - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Continuation from previous question: [Tensorflow - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635521/tensorflow-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable/58635565#58635583)

My training data is a list of lists each comprised of 1000 floats. For example, `x_train[0] =`

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, ...]
```

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu',
               input_shape=(1000, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\bencu\Desktop\ProjectFiles\Code\Program.py", line 88, in FitModel
        model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
        use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 224, in fit
        distribution_strategy=strategy)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 547, in _process_training_inputs
        use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 606, in _process_inputs
        use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 479, in __init__
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 321, in __init__
        dataset_ops.DatasetV2.from_tensors(inputs).repeat()
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 414, in from_tensors
        return TensorDataset(tensors)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 2335, in __init__
        element = structure.normalize_element(element)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\util\structure.py", line 111, in normalize_element
        ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i))
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1184, in convert_to_tensor
        return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1242, in convert_to_tensor_v2
        as_ref=False)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1296, in internal_convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 52, in _default_conversion_function
        return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 227, in constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_impl
        t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
        return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

I've tried googling the error myself, I found something about using the `tf.convert_to_tensor` function. I tried passing my training and testing lists through this but the function won't take them.

Comment: What outputs do you get for the following?: (1) `print(len(x_train))`; (2) `print(len(x_train[0]))`; (3) `print(x_train.shape)`; (4) `print(x_train[0].shape)`. If error, just skip the number

Comment: More importantly, it'd help to see your full code, as I cannot reproduce the issue with information provided. I suspect you're using variable input sizes, or your `x_train` list dimensions are inconsistent; what's the output for `for seq in x_train: print(np.array(seq).shape)`? Can [share here](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - `print(len(x_train))` outputs `13520`, `print(len(x_train[0]))` outputs `1000`, and the for loop outputs `(1000,)` for every single value in `x_train`.

Comment: What does the following output? `import sys; import tensorflow as tf; import keras; print(sys.version); print(tf.__version__); print(keras.__version__) # python ver, tf ver, keras ver` Also, are you able to share a subset of your data, via e.g. [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)?

Comment: verify x_train and x_test padding. If they are of different dimensions, this error can occur.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

**TL;DR** Several possible errors, most fixed with `x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')`.

Others may be faulty data preprocessing; ensure everything is *properly formatted* (categoricals, nans, strings, etc). Below shows what the model expects:

```py
[print(i.shape, i.dtype) for i in model.inputs]
[print(o.shape, o.dtype) for o in model.outputs]
[print(l.name, l.input_shape, l.dtype) for l in model.layers]
```

---

The problem's rooted in using *lists* as inputs, as opposed to Numpy arrays; Keras/TF doesn't support former. A simple conversion is: `x_array = np.asarray(x_list)`.

The next step's to ensure data is fed in expected format; for LSTM, that'd be a 3D tensor with dimensions `(batch_size, timesteps, features)` - or equivalently, `(num_samples, timesteps, channels)`. Lastly, as a debug pro-tip, *print ALL the shapes* for your data. Code accomplishing all of the above, below:

```py
Sequences = np.asarray(Sequences)
Targets   = np.asarray(Targets)
show_shapes()

Sequences = np.expand_dims(Sequences, -1)
Targets   = np.expand_dims(Targets, -1)
show_shapes()
```

```py
# OUTPUTS
Expected: (num_samples, timesteps, channels)
Sequences: (200, 1000)
Targets:   (200,)

Expected: (num_samples, timesteps, channels)
Sequences: (200, 1000, 1)
Targets:   (200, 1)
```

---

As a bonus tip, I notice you're running via `main()`, so your IDE probably lacks a Jupyter-like cell-based execution; I strongly recommend the [Spyder IDE](https://www.spyder-ide.org/). It's as simple as adding `# In[]`, and pressing `Ctrl + Enter` below:

[image]

---

**Function used**:

```py
def show_shapes(): # can make yours to take inputs; this'll use local variable values
    print("Expected: (num_samples, timesteps, channels)")
    print("Sequences: {}".format(Sequences.shape))
    print("Targets:   {}".format(Targets.shape))
```

Comment: I faced this issue when I inserted to a 3D numpy array to a pandas dataframe and then fetched numpy array from dataframe to create tensor object. To resolve this, I directly passed numpy array to create tensor object.

Comment: how can I fix that if my ytrain is an array of multi-label classes? (1000,20) 1000 records with 20 labels for each record?

Answer (score 95):

After trying everything above with no success, I found that my problem was that one of the columns from my data had `boolean` values. Converting everything into `np.float32` solved the issue!

```
import numpy as np

X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 26):

This should do the trick:

```
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: worked for me, but only after I did the same for x_test and y_test

Answer (score 18):

This is a HIGHLY misleading error, as this is basically a general error, which might have NOTHING to do with floats.

For example in my case it was caused by a string column of the pandas dataframe having some `np.NaN` values in it. Go figure!

Fixed it by replacing them with empty strings:

```
df.fillna(value='', inplace=True)
```

Or to be more specific doing this ONLY for the string (eg 'object') columns:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
for col in cols.columns.values:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna('')
```

Comment: `np.nan` is a float, so the nan is misleading you, not the error.

Answer (score 11):

Try with it for convert np.float32 to tf.float32 (datatype that read keras and tensorflow):

`tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train, dtype=tf.float32)`

Answer (score 5):

I had many different inputs and target variables and didn't know which one was causing the problem.

To find out on which variable it breaks you can add a print value in the library package using the path is specified in your stack strace:

```
      File "C:\Users\bencu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
        return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name,
```

Adding a `print` statement in this part of the code allowed me to see which input was causing the problem:

`constant_op.py`:

```py
  ....
      dtype = dtype.as_datatype_enum
    except AttributeError:
      dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
  ctx.ensure_initialized()
  print(value) # <--------------------- PUT PRINT HERE
  return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
```

After observing which value was problematic conversion from `int` to `astype(np.float32)` resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Could also happen due to a difference in versions (I had to move back from tensorflow 2.1.0 to 2.0.0.beta1 in order to solve this issue).

Comment: same here, I am trying to figure out what have been changed. Worked fine at version 1 too.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check data types in input data set or array and than convert it to `float32`:

```
train_X[:2, :].view()
#array([[4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
#       [5.9, 3.0, 5.1, 1.8]], dtype=object)
train_X = train_X.astype(np.float32)
#array([[4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
#       [5.9, 3. , 5.1, 1.8]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 3):

As answered by most people above, converting data in `np.float32 / float32`  by various means already told here.

While doing so if you get another error which is "`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`".

In that case, try converting your data into `type list` and then converting it into type tensor as you were trying earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use this, it is because of the uncompatible version of keras

```
from keras import backend as K
X_train1 = K.cast_to_floatx(X_train)
y_train1 = K.cast_to_floatx(y_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you are using a DataFrame and has multiple columns type:

```
numeric_list = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
df[numeric_list] = df[numeric_list].astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Would numpy.float64 work as good in this case as well?

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue and it ended up being because I was trying to pass an array of array objects, not an array of arrays as expected.

Comment: My error seems similar to yours. I've a sequence of 2-D array which I'm trying convert as arrary of arrays. Did you do np.stack to resolve it?

Comment: np.stack() resolved this error for me. I'm having some other issue during check-point which I'll debug separately.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
X_train =t ensorflow.convert_to_tensor(X_train, dtype=tensorflow.float32)
y_train = tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(y_train, dtype=tensorflow.float32)
X_test = tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(X_test, dtype=tensorflow.float32)
y_test = tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(y_test, dtype=tensorflow.float32)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer from OverLordGoldDragon provided valuable clues in my situation but I had to spend a few hours trying to rectify my particular situation. So adding some notes here to help any one else in a similar situation.

I am producing the input to my keras.Sequential `model.fit()` via the TimeseriesGenerator class from `keras.preprocessing.sequences` module. This class was outputting a 5d sequence with pythons inbuilt int/float types with following structure-

1. Level 5 - Batches(tuple of 10 batches since my batch size was 100
   samples for a training set containing 1000 items)
2. Level 4 - X and Y variables( tuple of 2 n-dimensional numpy arrays, one representing the x variable and the other the y variable for the batch)
3. Level 3
   3 dimensional nd numpy array of 100 samples each
   -for X variable a 100(batch size)x20(sequence length)x10(no of features) array,
   -for Y variable the last dimension is of size 1 instead of 10
4. Level 2 - each sample is a 2d array of 20(sequence length)x10(no of
   features) for x and 20x1 for y variable
5. Level 1 - is a scalar of
   native python types

When I followed the advise here and tried to convert this data structure to a `x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')`, this was failing as the standard output from TimeseriesGenerator has tuples instead of arrays/lists at the first two levels which are immutable and in-homogenous in length (as the last batch has fewer samples than the others since it can only take in the residual number of samples (79 in my case)).

I tried a lot of things to make this casting work on the ***output*** of TimeseriesGEnerator, but finally I found the simplest solution was to explicitly cast the ***inputs to the TimeseriesGenerator constructor*** using the suggested method (`x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')`). The problem was that these numpy nd arrays were being output by Preprocessing pipelines which retain native python int and float types in them. Once I cast these arrays to numpy float32 type, the model.fit() stopped giving the ValueError for failing to convert NumpyArray to TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't work to cast to `np.float32`.

For me, everything ran normally during training (probably because I was using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` as input for `fit()`), but when I was trying to call `predict()` on 1 instance (using a np.array), the error shows up.

As a solution, I had to reshape the array `x_array.reshape(1, -1)` before calling predict and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I avoided this problem by enforcing floating-point format during data import:

```
df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv', dtype='float')
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with some Pandas Series, thinking

```
data = my_series.to_numpy()
```

would be enough, but it would only provide an Object dtype and forcing to float64 or whatever didn’t work.

The issue was solved by using

```
data = my_series.to_list()
```

instead.  Then

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))
```

worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

First you check the format of your data, I suggest you to use LabelEncoder and StandardScaler to make the data normalised in a scale. For that,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler

X = lbl_encoder_1.fit_transform(X)
```

after splitting the X into train and test:

```
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)
```

and now set the model and then run the:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

Hope it will work, and you will not see that error. IF you still see the error then try to do:

```
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
```

and the same for y as well

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by bool columns that need to be converted to float. This does the trick:

```
for col in X_train.select_dtypes(include='bool').columns:
    X_train[col] = X_train[col].astype('float')
    X_test[col] = X_test[col].astype('float')
```