# i have problem with deep learning right input using pandas and list

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning

im trying to train a deep learning network for binary classification, but when i want to fit the model i have some errors depend on input data.
when im using a list which contains some list im getting this :

```
ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>,...
```

here is some of my input data:

```
    [[0.6136568,
  0.84256226,
  ....
  -0.8160665,
  -0.73415625],
 [0.14178441,
  -0.011213281,
  ....
  0.1529382,
  0.1492072],
 [-0.6528975,
  -0.5710656999999999,
  .....
```

for solving this error i tried to convert list to array, but now i have this error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

here is some of my input data:

```
array([list([0.6136568, .... ,  -0.8160665, -0.73415625]),
   list([0.14178441, ....., 0.1492072]), ....
```

here is my code:

```
def getRawData(x_data,y_data,dataset,label,window_size):
for i in range(0,dataset.size,window_size):
    
    x_data.append(dataset.iloc[i:i+window_size,].to_list())
    y_data.append(label)
x=[]
y=[]

getRawData(x,y,ds1,0,45)
getRawData(x,y,ds2,1,45)


getRawData(x,y,ds3,0,45)
getRawData(x,y,ds4,1,45)
num_units=64
learning_rate = 0.0001
activation_function = 'relu'
adam = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
loss_function = 'binary_crossentropy'
batch_size = 20
num_epochs = 300



model = Sequential()


model.add(LSTM(units = num_units,activation=activation_function,input_shape=(None,1)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(units = 1))
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=loss_function,metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(
    x,
    y,
    validation_split=0.1,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    shuffle=False
)
```

what is the problem ? what is the right input format?

Comment: have you tried to convert it to tensor? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641203/valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupported-object-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @bruck1701 I read convert to tensor document and i found the problem
the problem is convert to tensor cant covert array with different length in same dimension and i just did a mistake in my getRawData function