# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray) in Tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am creating a new Pandas Dataframe column using 4 other columns applying custom defined function row wise.

Below is the structure of the columns,  the function is applying on.

[image]

The new column created looks like this.

[image]

The function I wrote is as follows:

```
def convert_credit_rows(row):
  return np.asarray([row['A'], row['B'], row['C'], row['D']], dtype=np.float32)

X_train['credit_balance'] = X_train.apply(convert_credit_rows, axis=1)
X_test['credit_balance'] = X_test.apply(convert_credit_rows, axis=1)
```

I am providing this dataset to a simple neural network as follows:

```
def CreditBalanceDetector():

  X_train_credit_balance = X_train['credit_balance']
  X_test_credit_balance = X_test['credit_balance']

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0005), 
  metrics=['accuracy'])
  early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=3)
  model.fit(X_train_credit_balance, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=
  (X_test_credit_balance, y_test), callbacks=[early_stop])
```

But when trying to train the model I am getting the following error.

[image]

Though there are couple of similar questions in StackOverflow the solutions suggested there didn't work for me.

If someone could figure out where I'm going wrong that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I encountered that you answered a similar question like this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte. Could you please have a look at the above error and give some insights. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could figure out what went wrong in my code. Posting here for someone who may benefit in the future.

In the above code I have provided a Pandas Series object as the data type for both `X_train_credit_balance` and `X_test_credit_balance` where `model.fit()` function expects an array. If we inspect a single element of the `X_train_credit_balance` as follows,

```
print(X_train_credit_balance[0])
```

it will give the below output which is not what required:

```
array([30., 30.], dtype=float32)
```

**Correct Code**

The above behavior could be corrected by modifying the `convert_credit_rows(row)` function as follows:

```
credit_list = []

def convert_credit_rows(row):
  credit_list.append(np.asarray([row['A'], row['B'], row['C'], row['D']], dtype=np.float32))

 X_train_credit_balance = np.array(credit_list)
```

The`convert_credit_rows` function will be applied on each row creating a list of (m,n) dimensional array - credit_list in this case. Then as the next step we can convert the `credit_list` to a ndarray by `np.array(credit_list)`. If we print out the `credit_list` at the end of the operation we can see the correctly formatted array as follow:

```
[[1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 2. 3.]]
```

Now if we print out the type of the `X_train_credit_balance` it would be `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` instead of a Pandas Series object.