# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int). Tensorflow 1.15 runs. Tensorflow 2.x breaks

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, migration

System: Linux Manjaro

The full Error is:

```
    history = clf.fit(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 795, in fit
    data_adapter.train_validation_split((x, y, sample_weight),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1337, in train_validation_split
    train_arrays = nest.map_structure(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 617, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 617, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1334, in _split
    t = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(t)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1278, in convert_to_tensor_v2
    return convert_to_tensor(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1341, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 52, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 261, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 270, in _constant_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

I am training a CNN with the following code:

```
X2 = np.append(self.data.Img_Lr2_Train, self.data.Img_Lr2_Val, axis=0)
Y  = np.append(self.data.Y_Train, self.data.Y_Val, axis=0)
Y  = np.multiply(Y, 1)
X2, Y = shuffle(X2, Y, random_state=self.seed)
X2 = X2.reshape(X2.shape[0], 11, 7, 1)

history = clf.fit(
                  x=X2,
                  y=Y,
                  epochs=self.nEp,
                  batch_size=self.bt,
                  # shuffle=True,
                  validation_split=0.33,
                  callbacks=callbacks_list,
                  class_weight=class_weights
                  )
```

Following this ([Tensorflow - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte)) discusion I checked the variables type and shape:
which are all numpy arrays and are as expected.

Also the **MAIN ISSUE** is that when I run this with tensorflow 1.15 I don't get any problems.
However if I try runing with tensorflow 2.2 then I get the error.
I have tried migrating the code from tf_v1 -> tf_v2 using
`tf_upgrade_v2` 
both in `DEFAULT` and `SAFETY` mode,
and in both cases the process ends successfully.
However that didn't solve it.

Any idea where the problem might be?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not using `validation_split`,
instead what I did was to have:

```
X2_train= self.data.Img_Lr2_Train,
X2_val =  self.data.Img_Lr2_Val
Y_train=self.data.Y_Train, 
Y_val = self.data.Y_Val

X2_train = np.reshape(X2_train.shape[0], 11, 7, 1)
Y_train = np.reshape(Y_train.shape[0], 1)

# same with val arrays

X2_train =np.asarray(X2_train)
Y_train = np.asarray(Y_train)
```

I know the last step looks odd because all arrays are alreadt np.arrays,
but it worked.
Finally, I changed the fit function to:

```
history = clf.fit(
                  x=X2_train,
                  y=Y_train,
                  validation_data=(X2_val,Y_val),
                  epochs=self.nEp,
                  batch_size=self.bt,
                  # shuffle=True,
                  callbacks=callbacks_list,
                  class_weight=class_weights
                  )
```