# TensorFlow Dataset: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am aware that similar questions have been asked perviously but none of the proposed solutions seems to work for me. I have the following `Pandas` Dataframe:

|  | Title | Author | Target | Tag0 | Tag1 | Tag2 | Tag3 | Tag4 | Tag5 | Tag6 | Tag7 | Tag8 | Tag9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Says Ron Johnson referred to "The Lego Movie" as an "insidious anti-business conspiracy." | 0 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 36 | 35 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | "Forty percent of the Fortune 500 were started either by immigrants or children of immigrants." | 1 | 0 | 9 | 21 | 5 | 28 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

I have vectorised `Title` attribute by means of `TextVectorization` layer in `Keras` obtaining the following Dataframe:

|  | Title | Author | Target | Tag0 | Tag1 | Tag2 | Tag3 | Tag4 | Tag5 | Tag6 | Tag7 | Tag8 | Tag9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [9415, 19483, 9066, 16820, 20256, 6959, 6931,...,0 ] | 0 | 0 | 3213 | 3829 | 223 | 3140 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |

I want to transform this `Pandas` dataframe to a `TensorFlow` dataset. I have tried to achieve this using the following code:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data.values, target.values))
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

**By removing `Title` column the error goes away, then `Title` is the column that makes the error**. `Title` looks like this:

```
print(data["Title"].values)
```

```
array([array([ 9415., 19483.,  9066., 16820., 20256.,  6959.,  6931.,  8539.,
       10705.,  1342.,  1896.,  4353., 14143.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.],
       ...,
       array([17497., 20189.,  4280.,  3460., 20256., 15754.,  9178.,  1114.,
       19441., 18731., 13875., 14018.,  5789.,  6959.,  8740., 13042.,
         929.,  9541.,   773., 19384.,  5659., 13042., 14578.,  2813.,
       17452.,   888.,  6206.,  6959., 14540.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,
           0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.],
      dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

#### My question is: What is wrong with `Title`? What should I change ?

I am assuming that is related to the data type of the `numpy.ndarray` containing each `numpy.ndarray` title. As it be can seen above `dtype=object`. But I am not really sure.

Thank you in advance!

### Edit:

I found a work around to this issue by simply transforming the dataset to a `Numpy` ndarray.

```py
# To numpy
numpy_dataset = data.to_numpy(dtype="<U43")

#Get Target
target = data.pop("Target")

#TF dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((numpy_dataset, target.values))
```

Comment: Each cell of the `Title` column is an array.  `values` is then an array of arrays.  Try `np.stack(data["Title"].values)`.  If it raises an error, those nested arrays differ in shape, and cannot be made into a 2d numeric array (which `tensorflow` can use).

Comment: Great that solved my problem **but** partially. As you can see in the code above I pass the dataframe not only `Titles`. If I do what you suggested, `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.stack(data["Title"].values), target.values))` the `TensorFlow` dataset is created. But how can I include the remaining columns?

Comment: Other answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte/75139312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around to this issue by simply transforming the dataset to a `Numpy` ndarray.

```py
# To numpy
numpy_dataset = data.to_numpy(dtype="<U43")

#Get Target
target = data.pop("Target")

#TF dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((numpy_dataset, target.values))
```

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same question when I try the demo of tf feature_columns.ipynb.
I found the data contain null data,  after drop them, the code worked

```
    #drop null data
     dataframe = dataframe.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```