# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray) using fit_generator for LSTM autoencoder in Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning, generator

I am generating a dataset in batches to feed into an LSTM network in Keras.

Here is my generator:

```
    def generator(self):
            counter = 0
    
            #iterate while there are files
            while True:
                the_batch = list()
    
                #iterate for the size n of batches
                for b in range(self.batch_size):
                    filename = self.files[counter] #select file with index 'counter'
                    counter = (counter + 1) % len(self.files) #Ensures that each batch is divided (e.g 1 % 32 = 1, 2 % 32 = 2 etc)
                    df = pd.read_csv(self.data_path + "/" + filename, header=None) #Reads data for one sample
                    
                    the_batch.append(np.array(df)) #appends new sample data to batch list
                yield (np.array(the_batch), np.array(the_batch))  # convert the 3d list to 3D numpy array to feed into LSTM
```

When I fit my LSTM model in Keras using the generator above, like this:

```
 history = self.model.fit_generator(self.generator(),
                                               steps_per_epoch=steps, initial_epoch=self.start_idx, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks,
                                               validation_data=None, class_weight=None)
```

An error is produced where it says that the numpy array my generator outputs cannot be converted into a tensor that is used to fit in Keras. I'm not really sure what is wrong here as I am using `fit_generator` to fit my model:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Can someone see what I am doing wrong and please help? Thank you.

Comment: maybe take look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60750937/13273054)

Comment: Using the traceback, identify which expression raises the error, and within that figure out which array is the problem.  The examine that array, checking things like `shape` and `dtype`.  If object dtype, look at a few of the elements.  Often errors like this arise because the array is composed of arrays that differ in size.