# Numpy Array not Getting Converted to a Tensor - Tensorflow2

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to train a Neural Network for an NLP application in which I'm using a training set of 25000 examples. I pre-processed these examples into a feature vector of 25000 examples. I have only 3 features. I converted this feature vector into a numpy array using the general method

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

I now have a data set of shape (25000, 3). I compiled my model with input shape = (3, ) with my first layer being Embedding()

I passed a model fit query

```
history = model.fit(X, y, validation_split= 0.2, epochs = 30, verbose = 1, callbacks = [earlystop, modelcheckpoint, lr_red], 
                    batch_size = 256, shuffle = True
                    )
```

However, it gives me the error that

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

Even when I typed

```
print(X[0].shape)
```

It gave me (3, ), which is what the model should expect right?

Please help me to solve this issue. I really don't know where to even start fixing this.

Comment: I believe there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte) ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a problem with `x` datatype, not shape. Tensorflow is kind of strict about datatypes and doesn't support converting all of them (e.g. `int` as the error message states) to Tensors (which your Embedding layer is probably trying to do). I'd try the following:

```
X = np.array(X).astype('float32')
```

(If it doens't work, please provide full traceback)