# Tensorflow Convert To Tensor throws exception when trying to use numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train a model. Training Labels are stored in `training_labels` which is a  `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` . Each item in labels array has the following format of a `2d numpy array` with shape of `M * 5`.
`M` has a different value for each training example.( for example `(8, 5)` for first training example, `(3, 5)` for second training example).

I need to convert my labels to tensors and then use `padding` to have kind of a rectangular tensors.

Now i try to use `tensorflow.convert_to_tensor` to try to convert the `training_labels` to tensors, but it throws a `ValueError` exception like this :

`ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)`.

Now when i try to convert each of the `training_labels` to tensors individually,(for example

`tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(training_labels[0])`)

it works perfectly since it is just a one `2d numpy array`.

Now how can i convert my `training_labels` to tensors?

Comment: You can't.  While numpy can make an object dtype array from arrays that vary in shape (with a `ragged array` warning), `tensorflow` cannot convert that to a `tensor`.It's up to you do decide and do the padding before hand.

Comment: @hpaulj So before i start the training process i should try to pad the labels to fixed sizes like `F * 5` then convert the labels easily to tensors. but wouldn't it cause a problem when the there are more than `F` objects in the picture?

Comment: How you adjust the inputs to a consistent size depends on the model.  I won't presume to tell you what is the right way.  That's between you and the model developer.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60750937/14290681) reference help you to solve this issue?