# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I'm working with tensorflow and am coming across the following error in my code:
`ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type type).`
This occurs on this line:
`mlp.fit(puzzle_train, train_labels, epochs=10)`
Where puzzle_train and train_labels are defined as follows:

```py
puzzlesdb = list(np.load("data/matrix_rep%s.npz" % num, allow_pickle=True).values())
puzzle_train = puzzlesdb[:train_ind]

puzzle_labels = pd.read_csv("data/puzzle_data%s.csv" % num, 
                        names=["fen", "moves", "labels"]).pop("labels")
train_labels = puzzle_labels.head(train_ind)
```

Does anyone notice something immediately wrong with how I'm handling this?

Edit: If it helps, here's how I'm producing the .npz files:

````py
def dataConverter():
    for file in range(2, 13, 2):
        filename = "data/puzzle_data%s.csv" % file
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
        p = []
        for i in range(data.shape[0]):
            if (i % 500 == 0):
                print(i) 
            puzzle = pr(data[0][i], data[1][i], data[2][i].split(" "))
            p.append(puzzle.get_matrix_representation())
        np.savez_compressed("data/matrix_rep%s" % file, *p)```
````

Comment: One or both `puzzle_train, train_labels` is a object dtype array (or list), that contains lists or arrays that vary in shape.  A tensor can only be made from a numeric dtype array.

Comment: Agreed @hpaulj!  Could you try again by converting list of arrays to a single array ?Attaching similar  issues for reference .         https://stackoverflow.com/a/60750937/11530462