# How to change column containing list to one-hot-encoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, arraylist, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

[image]

This is what my columns look like. I would like to change the data in each column to one-hot-encoding.

The data is either [1,0,0],[0,1,0] or [0,0,1]

How can I do this?

Here is my code

```
def code_letter(letter):
return {
    'A':'2',
    'B':'1',
    'C':'1',
    'D':'1',
    'E':'2',
    'F':'1',
    'G':'1',
    'H':'1',
    'I':'2',
    'J':'1',
    'K':'1',
    'L':'1',
    'M':'1',
    'N':'1',
    'O':'2',
    'P':'1',
    'Q':'1',
    'R':'1',
    'S':'1',
    'T':'1',
    'U':'2',
    'V':'1',
    'W':'1',
    'X':'1',
    'Y':'2',
    'Z':'1'
}[letter]

# #preprocessing
def codify(word):
    n=[]
    for x in word:
        n.append(code_letter(x))
    n = ''.join(n)
    return n

def code_letter2(letter):
    return {
        '0':[1,0,0],
        '1':[0,1,0],
        '2':[0,0,1],
    }[letter]

def codify2d(word):
    n=[]
    for x in word:
        n.append(code_letter2(x))
    return n

def zerox(code):
    code_len = len(code)
    if code_len < 24:
        diff = 24 - code_len
        filled = code.ljust(diff + len(code), '0')
        return filled
    else:
        return code


def one_hot(final_code):
    final_split = list(final_code)
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(final_split)
    return dummies


dataset['Coded'] = dataset['Word'].apply(codify)
dataset['Codedfill'] = dataset['Coded'].apply(zerox)
dataset['Onehot'] = dataset['Codedfill'].apply(codify2d)
print(dataset)

dataset_new = pd.DataFrame(dataset.Onehot.tolist(), index= 
dataset.index)
dataset_new["Syllables"] = dataset["Syllables"]
print(dataset_new)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_dataset, test_dataset = train_test_split(dataset_new, 
test_size=0.2)

xtrain_dataset = train_dataset.loc[:, train_dataset.columns != 
'Syllables']
ytrain_dataset = train_dataset["Syllables"]

# Define a simple sequential model
def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Embedding(len(xtrain_dataset), 3, input_length=24))
  model.add(LSTM(18, dropout=0.1))
  model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu')),
  model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu')),
  model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

  optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model

#Create a basic model instance
model = create_model()
# Display the model's architecture
model.summary()

train_dataset.Syllables)
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = 
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,                          
    save_weights_only=True,verbose=1)

# Train the model with the new callback
#print(train_dataset)
model.fit(#train_dataset,
          x=xtrain_dataset,
          y=ytrain_dataset,
          epochs=50,
          batch_size=100,
          callbacks=[cp_callback])  # Pass callback to training

os.listdir(checkpoint_dir)
```

it gives

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)
```

when I try feeding the NN.

Comment: "[1,0,0],[0,1,0] or [0,0,1]" -> this is one hot encoding of 1, 2, 3

Comment: but I get an error when run: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).

Comment: trying to feed it to a NN

Comment: show us your code and paste the full error message , all in text format (not screenshot)

Comment: can you add a minimal code example of your problem?

Comment: hi @image357  I've added the code and the error message. I constructed the one-hot-encoding manually maybe that's what's responsible

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing the one hot encoding in your `code_letter2` function. I assume the only problem is your datatype. Try to convert your data to a numpy array before you feed it to your neural network, i.e.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')
```

See also this link for more details and options on your error:
[Tensorflow - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58636087/8088550)

Comment: yeah i tried that:
dataset = np.asarray(dataset['Onehot']).astype('float32')
It gives ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.