# How do I set up my x data correctly to train an LSTM model in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a machine learning model which predicts a single number from a series of numbers. I am using a Sequential model from the keras API of Tensorflow.

You can imagine my dataset to look something like this:

| Index | x data | y data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `np.ndarray(shape (1000000,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 1 | `np.ndarray(shape (1000000,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 2 | `np.ndarray(shape (1000000,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| 3 | `np.ndarray(shape (1000000,) )` | `numpy.float32` |
| ... | ... | ... |

**This was my first attempt:**

I tried using a numpy ndarray which contains numpy ndarrays which finally contain floats as my xdata, so something like this:

```py
array([
    array([3.59280851, 3.60459062, 3.60459062, ..., 4.02911493]) #the inner arrays have 1000000 elements each
    array([3.54752101, 3.56740332, 3.56740332, ..., 4.02837855])
    array([3.61048168, 3.62152741, 3.62152741, ..., 4.02764217])
    ...
])
```

My y data is a numpy ndarray containing floats, which looks something like this

```py
array([2.9864411, 3.0562437, ... , 2.7750807, 2.8712902], dtype=float32)
```

But when I tried to train the model using `model.fit()` it yields this error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

**You can have a closer look at my current try with this minimal example on Google Colab [here.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pNdDUoJpzUhLjHwMVXFvN1PcA2q-L2tx?usp=sharing)**

**Question:**
Easily said I just want my model to predict a number from a sequence of numbers.
For example like this:

- array([3.59280851, 3.60459062, 3.60459062, ...]) => 2.8989773
- array([3.54752101, 3.56740332, 3.56740332, ...]) => 3.0893357
- ...

**How can I use a sequence of numbers to predict a single number in Tensorflow?**

All in all I think that my question ist pretty general and should be easy to answer if you know how to tackle this problem, unlike me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58636087/14774959) can help you. I think that the problem is that an LSTM is expecting a 3D tensor as input `(batch_size, timesteps, features)`, but it is not getting that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my answer to some extent:

This is how I prepared my x data in the beginnning:

```py
x_train = np.asarray(train_set["input"])
```

Now I changed it to this:

```py
x_train = np.array([sub for sub in train_set["input"]]).reshape(3, 5, 1)
```

Because calling reshape on my first try directly did not work, I manually had to create the array from my dataset rather than calling `np.asarray`.