# Again about Tensorflow - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)

Tags: python, tensorflow

When executing the following tensorflow 2.8 method (after fitting *model*):

```
model.predict(X_test)
```

I get the following message:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)
```

None of suggestions reported in other similar questions seems to work.
Here's my data:

```
type(X_test)
X_test.size
len(X_test)
X_test
```

The outputs:

```
numpy.ndarray
13
13
array([array([[[[1.72707179e-04],
                [3.01862194e-04],
                [1.30811683e-03],
                ...,
                [3.52285788e-05],
                [5.02625953e-05],
                [6.48639834e-05]],

                [[7.46249643e-05],
                [4.26480168e-04],
                [2.55916407e-03],
                ...,
                [6.17124970e-05],
                [5.78219624e-05],
                [8.79297804e-05]],

               [[2.28419929e-04],
               [1.81215862e-03],
               [3.15412483e-03],

                etc
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `x_test.shape` and `x_test.dtype`?

Comment: Already been solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte)

Comment: @Djinn, x_test.shape --> (13,) x_test.dtype --> object

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an input sample of object type to model.predict(), hence the error. Please try  casting x_test to float32 using `tf.cast()` like below

```
x_test = tf.cast(x_test, tf.float32)
```

Input samples of a model.predict() could be:

- A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
- A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
- A tf.data dataset.
- A generator or keras.utils.Sequence instance. A more detailed description of unpacking behavior for iterator types (Dataset, generator, Sequence) is given in the Unpacking behavior for iterator-like inputs section of Model.fit.