# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray) error for a dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a determine quantity of `npy` files with 600 *279 dimentions. so this is my X and Y dataset to be processing with `tensorflow`

```
   y = np.asarray(lbllst).astype('float64') # numpy y data including all labels
   X = np.asarray(datadf)# numpy X labels including all voltages
   x_train = np.array([np.array(val) for val in X])
   y_train= np.array([np.array(val) for val in y])
   print(X.shape)
   print(y.shape)
   [-1.23311098e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99994955e+02, ...,
     -4.52300599e+02, -7.34672837e+01, -2.84649834e+01]])
     array([[ 1.24858387e+00,  1.08855569e-01,  3.73679890e-01, ...,
     -1.93123977e+02,  2.23770733e+00, -6.32500982e+01],
    [ 1.16805872e+00,  1.09343905e-01,  3.56978019e-01, ...,
     -1.65375302e+02,  1.91437743e+00, -6.55327423e+01],
    [ 1.09272688e+00,  1.09291322e-01,  3.40279053e-01, ...,
     -1.35757021e+02,  1.59499768e+00, -6.78354772e+01],
    ...,
    [ 2.46976759e-06,  1.17603859e-02,  1.92456598e-01, ...,
     -1.55013187e+02, -2.92794938e+00, -1.39634507e+02],
    [ 2.31050154e-06,  9.97854342e-03,  1.89263633e-01, ...,
     -1.31052482e+02, -3.07873820e+00, -1.40427623e+02],
    [ 2.16153593e-06,  8.14650308e-03,  1.86245435e-01, ...,
     -1.06577450e+02, -3.22932304e+00, -1.41237221e+02]])
     array([[-4.45263092e+02, -4.60675331e+02,  4.78848517e+02, ...,
     -4.31455701e+02,  6.15445633e+01, -8.77422660e+00],
    [-4.34941026e+02, -4.85213343e+02,  4.83231725e+02, ...,
     -4.33033072e+02,  6.22573512e+01, -1.04613412e+01],
    [-4.23671013e+02, -4.94517978e+02,  4.86707603e+02, ...,
     -4.34416831e+02,  5.87750151e+01, -1.20913343e+01],
    ...,
    [-1.40890973e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99994636e+02, ...,
     -4.53766069e+02, -7.11878828e+01, -2.78512654e+01],
    [-1.31804498e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99994575e+02, ...,
     -4.55753496e+02, -7.24276912e+01, -2.76229014e+01],
    [-1.23304035e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99994509e+02, ...,
     -4.57552190e+02, -7.36213174e+01, -2.74249806e+01]])
     array([[-4.99807796e+02, -3.73888978e+02,  4.96305657e+02, ...,
     -4.97178363e+02, -6.44659178e+01, -4.53129472e+01],
    [-4.99666293e+02, -4.81502569e+02,  4.97417158e+02, ...,
     -4.97298848e+02, -7.76075378e+01, -4.82890050e+01],
    [-4.99440916e+02, -4.97508494e+02,  4.98243246e+02, ...,
     -4.97411818e+02, -9.00829300e+01, -5.11549069e+01],
    ...,
    [-4.23173680e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99999996e+02, ...,
      3.74225305e+02, -3.23626902e+02,  7.38237031e+01],
    [-3.95881921e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99999996e+02, ...,
      3.82536389e+02, -3.31592627e+02,  8.22769680e+01],
    [-3.70350291e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99999996e+02, ...,
      3.90070336e+02, -3.38951581e+02,  9.00407982e+01]])
     array([[-4.99807796e+02,  4.93239182e+02,  4.92230632e+02, ...,
     -3.66177250e+02,  1.20811824e+02, -5.14159837e+00],
    [-4.99666293e+02,  4.44743992e+02,  4.93809614e+02, ...,
     -3.67056782e+02,  1.11921314e+02, -6.01090274e+00],
    [-4.99440916e+02,  1.61288976e+02,  4.95059744e+02, ...,
     -3.67824643e+02,  9.55413945e+01, -6.93508205e+00],
    ...,
    [-4.23172820e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99999998e+02, ...,
      2.38758241e+02, -4.13026747e+02,  1.85680990e+02],
    [-3.95881107e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99999998e+02, ...,
      2.43155495e+02, -4.12497798e+02,  1.85073187e+02],
    [-3.70349536e-03, -5.00000000e+02,  4.99999998e+02, ...,
      2.47646739e+02, -4.11954504e+02,  1.84424236e+02]])   ]
    (96,)
    (96,)
```

but when I try to create a sequentioal model I get an error. this is my moddel:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(96,input_shape=(X[0].shape), activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

])
model.summary()
# model.fit(x_train, y, verbose=0, epochs=100)


# For a multi-class classification problem
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', 
                               mode='max', # don't minimize the accuracy!
                               patience=10,
                               restore_best_weights=True)

model.fit(
x_train, 
y, 
batch_size=32, 
epochs=10, verbose=2, 
callbacks=None, 
validation_split=0.2, 
validation_data=None, 
shuffle=True, 
class_weight=None, 
sample_weight=None, 
initial_epoch=0)
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)
```

Comment: What is the object type and dtype of `y`? Is that not supposed to be `y_train` in fit?

Comment: Hi @Saharitttto, could you please refer to the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte) and let us know if it helps to resolve the issue or not. Thank You.