# Is there any method that solve unsupported object type float error in complie?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, matplotlib

`I tried to make a model that covers missing values with mean, and show results of  training set and validation set at the same time.

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

targetURL='../content/drive/MyDrive/1-2/caffeine.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(targetURL)

df=pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['sex'])

df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(4)
df=df.fillna(df.mean(numeric_only=True))

standardization_df = (df - df.mean(numeric_only=True,axis=0)) / df.std(numeric_only=True,axis=0)

x=standardization_df.iloc[:,1:14]
y=df.iloc[:,14]
y=pd.get_dummies(y)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, shuffle=True,random_state=3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24,  input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

score=model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=10, verbose=0, validation_split=0.2)
hist_df=pd.df(history.history)

y_vloss=hist_df['val_loss']
y_loss=hist_df['loss']
x_len=np.arange(len(y_loss))

plt.plot(x_len, y_vloss, "o", c="red", makersize=2, label='Testset_loss')
plt.plot(x_len, y_loss, "o", c="blue", makersize=2, label='Trainset_loss')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.show()
```

`
However, I got problem in line 34(history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=10, verbose=0, validation_split=0.2)). It showed me 'Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)'.  I want to know how and where do I have to fix with this code.

For further information of this df, there's two columns filled with texts. They're 'sex' and 'target'. As you can guess, they have two answers each(female-male/yes-no).

Comment: Which one is line 35?

Comment: "history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=10,verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)" is the line 35

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte