# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray). with RESNET feature extraction

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, tensor, feature-extraction, resnet

I am trying to extract features from my images using RESNET50, however, I keep getting an error when trying to run prediction.
[image: Error image]

I have tried doing some research but that does not seem to work at all. The research link I used for solving the issue: [Similar error but no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636087/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensor-unsupporte)

I have two sets of images and two sets of labels concatenated into one `images` variable and one `labels` variable. The code below shows the process of normalizing both sets of images then converting them into a numpy array. After, the process is done, I split the dataset.

Keep in mind, that I am using numpy arrays throughout.

```py
all_Images_Normalize = all_Images / 255.0
hem_Images_Normalize = hem_Images / 255.0

all_Images_Normalize = np.array(all_Images_Normalize, dtype=object)
hem_Images_Normalize = np.array(hem_Images_Normalize, dtype=object)

images = np.concatenate((all_Images_Normalize, hem_Images_Normalize), axis=0)
labels = np.concatenate((all_labels_in_array, hem_labels_in_array), axis=0)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Extract features using RESNET50 model with RGB images
resnet = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(210, 210, 3))

for layer in resnet.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    
resnet.summary()
```

Hope my question is clear. Let me know if any clarification is needed.

I have tried using the following before using the predict() function with RESNET. I get another error showing: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

```py
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Does `np.asarray(x_train)` give you a warning about 'ragged' arrays?  Your data is not consistent in size.