# Which axis does Keras SimpleRNN / LSTM use as the temporal axis by default?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

When using a `SimpleRNN` or `LSTM` for classical [sentiment analysis](https://keras.io/examples/imdb_lstm/) algorithms (applied here to sentences of length <= 250 words/tokens):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 32, input_length=250))   # Output shape: (None, 250, 32)
model.add(SimpleRNN(100))                          # Output shape: (None, 100)
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))          # Output shape: (None, 1)
```

**where is it specified which axis of the input of the RNN is used as the "temporal" axis?**

To be more precise, after the `Embedding` layer, a given input sentence, e.g. *"the cat sat on the mat"*, is encoded into a matrix `x` of shape (250, 32), where 250 is the max length (in words) of the input text, and 32 the dimension of the embedding. Then, where in Keras is it specified if this will be used:

1. `h[t] = activation( W_h * x[:, t] + U_h * h[t-1] + b_h )`

or this:

2. `h[t] = activation( W_h * x[t, :] + U_h * h[t-1] + b_h )`

(In both cases, `y[t] = activation( W_y * h[t] + b_y )`)

**TL;DR: if an input for a RNN Keras layer is of size, say, (250, 32), which axis does it use as the temporal axis by default? Where is this detailed in the Keras or Tensorflow documentation?**

---

PS: how to explain the number of parameters (given by `model.summary()`) which is 13300? `W_h` has 100x32 coefs, `U_h` has 100x100 coefs, `b_h` has 100x1 coefs, i.e. we already have 13300! There is no coefs left for `W_y` and `b_y`! How to explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Temporal axis**: it's always dim 1, unless `time_major=True`, then it's dim 2; the `Embedding` layer outputs a 3D tensor. This can be seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L540) where `step_input_shape` is the shape of input fed to the RNN `cell` at each step in the [recurrent loop](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L784). For your case, `timesteps=250`, and the SimpleRNN cell "sees" a tensor shaped `(batch_size, 32)` at each step.

---

**# of params**:  you can see how the figure's derived by inspecting each layer's `.build()` code: [Embedding](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/embeddings.py#L135), [SimpleRNN](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1293), [Dense](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1147), or likewise calling `.weights` on each layer. For your case, w/ `l = model.layers[1]`:

- `l.weights[0].shape == (32, 100)` --> 3200 params (`kernel`)
- `l.weights[1].shape == (100, 100)` --> 10000 params (`recurrent_kernel`)
- `l.weights[2].shape == (100,)` --> 100 params (`bias`) (**sum: 13,300**)

---

**Computation logic**: there is no `W_y` or `b_y`; the "y" is the hidden state, `h`, actually for all recurrent layers - what you cite are likely from generic RNN formulae. @ "in  both cases..." - this is false; to see what's actually happening, inspect the [`.call()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1321) code.

P.S. I recommend defining the full `batch_shape` of the model for debugging, as it eliminates the ambiguous `None` shapes

---

**SimpleRNN formula vs. code**: as requested; note the `h` in source code is misleading, and is typically `z` in formulae ("pre-activation").

[image]

- `return_sequences=True` -> outputs for *all* timesteps are returned:  `(batch_size, timesteps, channels)`
- `return_sequences=False` -> only *last* timestep's output is returned: `(batch_size, 1, channels)`. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L807)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer, it is very helpful.

Comment: Just to be 100%, could you just include the formulae for SimpleRNN? `h[t] = activation( W_kernel * x[t, :] + W_recurrentkernel * h[t-1] + W_bias )` (where * is a dot product) seems more or less correct. But what is the **output** of the SimpleRNN, since there is no specific `y[t]`? Would it be `h[-1]`, i.e. the output of the hidden state for the last timestep?

Comment: Wonderful answer @OverLordGoldDragon!

Comment: PS: why `return output, [output]`? i.e. why return an output + the same output packed inside a list?

Comment: @Basj One's for the output `y`, another is to carry the RNN state ([`states`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L785)), which can (and does for [LSTM](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2438)) include more than `y`.