# Tensorflow keras Input shape claimed as (None, None) while printed out as (20, 30)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to make a CNN-LTSM model with Keras, and I want to use keras.utils.Sequence to feed data into model (as the data is continuous, and I want every available window in the data be used for training).

But then Keras keeps complaining about the shape of my input data.

Error:

```
Epoch 1/100
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 20, 30) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 20, 30), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_7'), name='input_7', description="created by layer 'input_7'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None).

Cell 5 line 2
     15 dataSeq = TrainDataFeedSequence(train, INPUT_SIZE)
     17 # for i in range(0, len(dataSeq)):
     18 #     curInputShape = dataSeq.__getitem__(i)[0].shape
     19 #     if (curInputShape[0] == None or curInputShape[1] == None or curInputShape == (None, None)):
     20 #         print(dataSeq.__getitem__(i)[0])
---> 22 model.fit(x=dataSeq, epochs=100, verbose=1)

in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_6" "                 f"(type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "conv1d_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, None)
```

My Code for my sequence

```python
class TrainDataFeedSequence(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, data, batch_size):
        self.data = data
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data) - self.batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        inputs = self.data.iloc[idx:idx+self.batch_size,:]
        targets = self.data.iloc[idx+self.batch_size,:1]
        return (inputs, targets)

dataSeq = TrainDataFeedSequence(train, 20)

# this prints out nothing
# for i in range(0, len(dataSeq)):
#     curInputShape = dataSeq.__getitem__(i)[0].shape
#     if (curInputShape[0] == None or curInputShape[1] == None or curInputShape == (None, None)):
#         print(dataSeq.__getitem__(i)[0])

model.fit(x=dataSeq, epochs=100)
```

I'm quite sure that every item in my Sequence are not in shape (None, None), so what goes wrong?

keras == 2.10.0,tensorflow == 2.10.0, python == 3.9.18

I tried to print out all the shape of input items as well and all of them are in shape (20, 30).

Comment: What, exactly, is `dataSeq`?  For many inputs, `model.fit` requires both X and Y.

Comment: @TimRoberts https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence

Comment: In model.fit, parameter x:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit
A generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever wants to know, it's because of the `TrainDataFeedSequence` doesn't return `input` and `targets` as `np.Array`

making two `np.Array` with inputs and targets and return them solved the error

working version:

```
class TrainDataFeedSequence(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, data, batch_size):
        self.data = data
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data) - self.batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        inputs = self.data.iloc[idx:idx+self.batch_size,:]
        targets = self.data.iloc[idx+self.batch_size,:1]
        return np.array(inputs), np.array(targets)

dataSeq = TrainDataFeedSequence(train, 20)

# this prints out nothing
# for i in range(0, len(dataSeq)):
#     curInputShape = dataSeq.__getitem__(i)[0].shape
#     if (curInputShape[0] == None or curInputShape[1] == None or curInputShape == (None, None)):
#         print(dataSeq.__getitem__(i)[0])

model.fit(x=dataSeq, epochs=100)
```

Worth mentioning that this exact hand-made Sequence is responsible for screwing up my training process, so better don't use it directly, [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276337/proper-way-to-feed-time-series-data-to-stateful-lstm/58277760#58277760)